# How to cancel / unset a DoFn defined timer?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Having read [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) and looked at the JavaDoc for a [Timer](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/Timer.html), I have successfully setup a timer to be fired.  However, I am missing how to request that a timer be cancelled before it has fired.  Is this a semantic that is possible / allowable in Beam architecture?

My back-story is that I wish to register a timer to fire a callback if something has not occurred ... but if it HAS occurred prior to the timer firing, then I wish to cancel the timer from being fired.

Comment: This seems like a bug that we should fix. If you feel up to it, please file a bug in the Apache Beam JIRA.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7167 has been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to cancel the time. However, you can use a Boolean value state to skip the processing onTime when timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

You can [cancel timers](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.32.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/Timer.html#clear--) as of Beam SDK 2.32.0.